# Regexp match everything between two dots including the last word and first word(excluding dots), JavaScript .match()

Tags: javascript, regex

Test Strings:

```
first.second.third.last
```

Match result:

```
first
second
third
fourth
```

I was able to match only for `first.second` using pattern `.*(?=\.)|(?<=\.).*`.

When I use this in console `"licence.name".match(/(.*(?=\.))|(?<=\.).*/)`, it returns an Array with *licence*, on regex101.com the result is different it match produces:

*match 1* `licence`

*match 2* `''`

*match 3* `name`

[image: regex101 match]

[image: console match]

Why is the match result different for JavaScript and [regex101.com](https://regex101.com)?

What I want is, in JavaScript `match()` function to return the desired match array.

Comment: Why you does not use `split('.')`?

Comment: @Mohammad It can be helpful in future as well, `split('.')` is language specific, regex in universal

Comment: Regex might be 'universal', however there are so many flavors, that you can't rely on that.

Comment: @PoulBak True, I have faced the music of its many flavours.

Answer (score -1):

You have to add the modifier `g` to your regex, to retrive all results and not only the first match.
On the first picture of regex101.com you can see that the service applies `gm` as modifiers to the regex. But the `m` is only necessary when you have multi line strings and you want to match also results on other lines.

```
"licence.name".match(/(.*(?=\.))|(?<=\.).*/g);
//["licence", "", "name"]
```

Have a look at the msdn article of [String.prototype.match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match):

> If the regular expression does not include the g flag, str.match()
>   will return the same result as RegExp.exec(). The returned Array has
>   an extra input property, which contains the original string that was
>   parsed. In addition, it has an index property, which represents the
>   zero-based index of the match in the string.
>
> **If the regular expression includes the g flag, the method returns an
>   Array containing all matched substrings rather than match objects.
>   Captured groups are not returned. If there were no matches, the method
>   returns null.**